# Installing eclipse by apt-get

Tags: apt, android, eclipse

My favorable method for installing is always `apt-get`. Fortunately, `eclipse` is now included in `apt-get` repository. However, when I installed it with `apt-get`, it works fine for programming languages such as C/C++; but when I try to install `Android Developer SDK`, it gives an error for missing `org.eclipse.ui`.

I found several questions about this error, but no solution for `apt-get install` . The only solution is to install classic eclipse from source. I believe there should be a solution to install `org.eclipse.ui` with `apt-get install`.

Comment: Have you checked that you have installed all possible plugins from the repository?

Comment: I installed with these comments `sudo apt-get install eclipse`, `sudo apt-get install eclipse-jdt`, `sudo apt-get install eclipse-cdt` ... what plugin should I install? I did not find any document for installing eclipse plugins with `apt-get`

Comment: run `sudo aptitude` and search for everything `eclipse`.  On top of this you can install plugins directly while running Eclipse, via `Help->Install New Software`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to install all of the following packages and dependencies:

```
eclipse
eclipse-jdt
eclipse-pde
eclipse-platform
eclipse-rcp
```

Once that was done I was able to install `Android SDK` without any issues through Eclipse.  I am running on `openjdk`.